# QuantLib-Python: Getting a list of all holidays between D1 & D2 with function "holidayList"

Tags: python, quantlib

I figured out that the C++ version of QuantLib offers a function called holidayList in the calendar class.

```
//! Returns the holidays between two dates
static std::vector<Date> holidayList(const Calendar& calendar,
                                     const Date& from,
                                     const Date& to,
                                     bool includeWeekEnds = false);
```

I tried to get all holidays between two dates by using this call:

```
TARGET_calendar = TARGET()
TARGET_calendar.holidayList(TARGET_calendar, Date(1,1,2015), Date(1,1,2016))

AttributeError: 'TARGET' object has no attribute 'holidayList'
```

Since I am not so familliar with converting C++ to Python, I also tried:

```
holidayList(TARGET_calendar, Date(1,1,2015), Date(1,1,2016))

NameError: name 'holidayList' is not defined
```

Can anybody help me out, please?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `holidayList()` function is not exposed in Python: https://github.com/lballabio/QuantLib-SWIG/blob/master/SWIG/calendars.i

You can submit an issue asking for it to be added, or do it yourself via a pull request or just locally but in this last case you'd have to rebuild the QuantLib Python library, etc.

As a workaround, you can use the `isHoliday()` function in order to get this list, combined with `isWeekend()` if you want want to exclude the weekends from the holidays list:

```
TARGET_calendar = TARGET()
date = Date(1,1,2015)
holiday_list = []
while date < Date(1,1,2016):
    if(TARGET_calendar.isHoliday(date) and not
       TARGET_calendar.isWeekend(date.weekday())):
        holiday_list.append(date)
    date = date + Period(1, Days)
```

Comment: In case you want to open an issue, the place to do it is https://github.com/lballabio/QuantLib-SWIG/issues.

Comment: Dear byouness, dear Luigi! Thank you very much for your answers. The workaround warks like a charm. Thanks! Unfortunately I am a beginner in Python and have no idea about C++ so I am not able to integrate the function myself. I have opened an issue here: https://github.com/lballabio/QuantLib-SWIG/issues/112

Comment: Hello @BerndMeyer! Glad that this helped. If it answers your question, please mark it as accepted so that people who have the same question can find it more quickly. Thanks.